# Double sided modulus equation: $|2x-1| = |3x+2|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Considering this equation $$|2x-1| = |3x+2|$$
My question is what is the reasoning behind taking only the positive and negative values of one side of the equation to solve the problem. I have seen many people do that and it seems to work. 
For e.g., $$2x-1 = 3x+2$$ 
          $$2x-1 = -(3x+2),$$ 
then solve for $x$.On the other hand, I have been taught that I should be testing both positive and negative values on both sides which will eventually give 4 cases to solve instead of 2. This makes more sense since disregarding the absolute value sign give rise to the situation, a negative and positive value.

Comment: The equations $2x-1 = 3x+2$ and $-(2x-1) = -(3x+2)$ have the same solutions. It might look like you have four cases, but two pairs of them are identical, so you're just duplicating your work.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that there are four possibilities with

$|a| =|b|$

So $\pm a = \pm b$

1) $a = b$.

2) $a = -b$

3) $-a = b$

4) $-a = -b$

But notice

A) $a = b \iff -a = -b$.  So 1) and 4) are the exact same thing!

and

B) $a = -b$ \iff -a = b$ so 2) and 3) are the exact same thing.

So for $|2x-1| = |3x+2|$

and $\pm(2x-1) = \pm(3x+2)$ there are two options:

A) $2x-1 = 3x+ 2$  (which would also mean $-(2x-1) = -(3x +2)$.)

or

B)  $2x - 1 = -(3x+2)$ (which would also mean $-(2x-1) = 3x + 2$.)

......

In other words $|a|  = |b| \iff \pm a = \pm b \iff a = \pm b \iff \pm a = b$.

But in a comment above Yolo Inver raises a good point about *inequalities*:

$|a| < |b| \implies -|b| < -|a| \le 0 \le |a| < |b| \implies$ four possibilities: $-b< -a \le 0 \le   a < b$  OR $b < a \le 0 \le a < b$  OR $-b < a \le 0 \le -a < b$  OR $b< -a \le  0 \le  a < -b$.

For inequalities there are $4$ cases to consider.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this workaround is much easier the case for inequalities, and would be squaring both sides to eliminate the negative. This also helps avoiding the individual $4$ cases.

$$|2x-1|^2 = |3x+2|^2$$

$$4x^2-4x+1=9x^2+12x+4$$

$$5x^2+16x+3=0$$

Thus, (spoiler below)

> $$(5x+1)(x+3)=0 \implies x=-3, -\frac 15$$

Comment: If you are eliminating the negatives, doesnt it mean that you are also eliminating possible solutions for x?

Comment: I don't get what you mean @Raynezick. Take:$$-x-4=0$$ If you multiply both sides by $-1$, you get $$x+4=0$$ How are you "eliminating possible solutions"?

Comment: Ok now i see it

Comment: @rayne Please consider marking it correct if you think it is correct.

Comment: You're kidding, right?  Who on earth would think solving a quadratic is simpler the taking cases.  $2x -1 =3x+2\implies x = -3$ and $2x - 1 = 2-3x\implies x = 5$.  Obviously you made some error if you got an irrational solution to linear integer equations.

Comment: @fleablood"In my opinion", quadratics are easier than tackling multiple cases. Especially when dealing with inequalities, when there ARE going to be 4 cases.

Comment: $(2x -1)^2 = 4x^2 - 4x + 1$ not $4x^2 - 4x -1$.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks.

Comment: Who said anything about downvoting?

Comment: we're only talking two cases and when you square you add the risk of extraneous roots.  And this doesn't answer the question: why do two instead of four cases?  You just answered don't bother, do something else.

Comment: @fleablood $2x-1 = 2-3x \implies 5x = 1$

Comment: @YoloInver I've noticed you deleted a question recently on finding a quadratic that has some given roots.

Comment: @YoloInver Please don't delete questions that someone has answered. When people answer or comment to help you get the right answer, deleting it loses that information, especially for people who have a similar question. If you really think that your question is that bad, leave it for others to decide by flagging.

Comment: @fleablood, you write "when you square you add the risk of extraneous roots." In general yes, but not for a problem like this one, with absolute values on both sides:  $f(x)=|g(x)|\implies f(x)^2=g(x)^2$ can give extraneous real roots, but $|f(x)|=|g(x)|\iff f(x)^2=g(x)^2$ cannot.

Answer (score 0):

In this example you actually can reduce this to two cases.  Either the expressions inside the absolute values share the same sign, or they have opposite signs.

If you assume the left is negative and the right is positive.

$-(2x-1) = 3x + 2$

And the case the the right is positive and the left is negative.

$2x -1 = -(3x+2)$

You will get the same solutions.  However, for one case, the results are in contradiction to the assumption.

If you have a more if you added in something not inside the absolute value brakets... e.g. $|x+1| - |2x-1| = 1$

You should be testing all 4 cases.  Or  $x<-1, -1<x<\frac 12, \frac 12<x$ will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually just two cases. Case I:
$$2x - 1 = 3x + 2$$
yields $x = -3$.

Now for case II:
$$2x - 1 = -3x - 2$$
yields $x = -1/5$.

No quadradic machinery required.